# 4 tasks with company address problems

Tags: sql-server

I have 4 tasks:

1. I want to select the cIds (company´s) where the company adress (combination of company name(company), street(street) and postcode(code)) is not the CURRENT delivery adress (combination of company name (del), street (street 2) and postcode (cod2) anymore => orders have been send to another adress, after the adress was used the first time (Use the date of first order of the adress (Date1) and newest order to this adress (Date2). [No orders to actual company adress anymore]
2. I want to select the rows cIds(company´s) where the company adress (combination of company name(company), street(street) and postcode(code)) IS THE ACTUAL DelIVERY ADRESS FOR MIN 1 YEAR and is not the CURRENT delivery adress (combination of company name (del), street (street 2) and postcode (cod2) anymore => orders have been send to another adress, after the adress was used for min 1 year (Use the date of first order of the adress (Date1) and newest order to this adress (Date2). [No orders to company adress anymore & company adress was the delivery adress for min 1 year]
3. I want to select the cIds(company´s) where the company adress (combination of company name(company), street(street) and postcode(code)) is the CURRENT delivery adress (combination of company name (del), street (street 2) and postcode (cod2) AND orders have also been send to another adress, after the adress was used the first time (Use the date of first order of the adress (Date1) and newest order to this adress (Date2). 
   [orders to actual company adress and to another adress]
4. I want to select the cIds(company´s) where the company adress (combination of company name(company), street(street) and postcode(code)) is the CURRENT delivery adress (combination of company name (del), street (street 2) and postcode (cod2) FOR MIN 1 YEAR AND orders have also been send to another adress, after the adress  was used for min 1 year (Use the date of first order of the adress (Date1) and newest order to this adress (Date2). 
   [orders to actual company adress and to another adress]

cID = ID of company

Date 1= Date of first order

Date 2= Date of last/newest order

Here´s some data to make it easier to understand:

```
|cID ||company|Street  |Code|del     |Street2 |Cod2|Date 1    |Date 2    |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1   ||Ex1    |ABC Rd.1|4025|Ex1     |DEL St.1|0212|01.01.2015|06.03.2015|
|1   ||Ex1    |ABC Rd.1|4025|Ex1     |REF Wy.1|9875|26.02.2015|16.05.2015|
|1   ||Ex1    |ABC Rd.1|4025|Ex1     |ABC Rd.1|4025|13.06.2015|18.07.2016|
|1   ||Ex1    |ABC Rd.1|4025|Ex1     |RAD St.7|1238|13.08.2016|08.08.2017|
|2   ||Ex2    |HIO Wy.1|9999|Ex2     |DEL St.1|0212|13.03.2015|09.07.2015|
|2   ||Ex2    |HIO Wy.1|9999|Ex2     |REG St.1|6754|21.02.2015|16.05.2015|
|2   ||Ex2    |HIO Wy.1|9999|Ex2     |BLA Rd.5|0897|01.03.2015|06.12.2015|
|2   ||Ex2    |HIO Wy.1|9999|Ex2     |HIO Wy.1|9999|09.01.2017|26.06.2017|
|2   ||Ex2    |HIO Wy.1|9999|Ex2     |RAD St.7|1238|13.07.2017|08.08.2017|
|3   ||Ex3    |REG St.1|1114|Ex3     |REG St.1|1114|21.03.2015|16.04.2017|
|3   ||Ex3    |REG St.1|1114|Ex3     |DEL St.9|0212|13.11.2016|09.02.2017|
|4   ||Ex4    |FAR RD.9|4567|Ex4     |FAR RD.9|4567|09.10.2016|26.12.2016|
|4   ||Ex4    |FAR RD.9|4567|Ex4     |DDR Wy.2|0897|01.03.2017|06.07.2016|
```

Result

Task 1: cID 2

Task 2: cID 1

Task 3: cID4

Task 4: cID 3

This is my actual working point and I´m not able to go on- I know that there are 4 diffent codes to write, but I have not really an idea how to start even one of them :(

```
SELECT cID
FROM Table1
WHERE Street = Street2 
AND Code = Cod2 
AND Date1 > ( 
            SELECT !=MAX(Date2)
            FROM Table1 as delivery
            WHERE Table1.cID = delivery.cID 
             AND (delivery.Street2 <> Street OR delivery.Cod2 <> Code)
          )
```

-> Please do me a favour and mark the task where you think you got an answer for

Comment: Can the codes be used to determine unique addresses?

Comment: I don´t really understand what you mean :/

Answer (score 0):

## 1:

```
;with cte as
(
select cID ,company,Street  ,Code,del,Street2 ,Cod2,[Date 1],[Date 2]
   , row_number() over (partition by cID order by [Date 1]) rnfirst
   , row_number() over (partition by cID order by [Date 2] desc) as rnLast
from Table1  
)
select t1.cID
from cte t1
join cte t2 on t1.cId=t2.cID
where t2.rnLast=1
 and t1.rnFirst = 1
 and (t1.Street<>t2.Street2 or t1.Code<>t2.Cod2)
```

Comment: i didn't see something you requested. the first order compared to latest order. i'll add that

Comment: I don´t get what your saying - unfortunately my English is not the best (sorry for that). I would like to answer you, but do not understand what you want from me